# Lost connection with OP

Tags: support

I got a stack exchange email, and the partial first line indicated that the OP wanted to ask me additional questions about my answer.  However, when I clicked on the thread, that question was gone. I am wondering if one of the moderators deleted it because it was not really relevant (wouldn't know because I never saw the question).  However, the OP is a student, and I would like to respond to student questions.  Is there some way to move that potential discussion to a chat, and if so how?  Or could OP send me a private message and if so, how?

Comment: Are you familiar with the site's chat feature?

Comment: Try the link again.  (If it is the question I think it was, I have a feeling the student was trying to hide tracks by deleting evidence of the question being asked.)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by a "stack exchange email"?  The email address associated to your account is private, and there is no "send email to user" feature here. I suspect that this student tracked you down using other means/Google to contact you.

Comment: If someone leaves a comment to you, either by commenting on a post made by you or by replying to one of your comments using `@BettyMock` in their comment, a message will be left in your StackExchange inbox. If that comment is later deleted, by the author or a moderator, you will still see the comment in your inbox. Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: @robjohn: I didn't even think of that interpretation... seems _much_ more likely than mine.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Yes robjohn's explanation is what happened. The student didn't track me down (altho I imagine it's easy enough) -- he left a comment on the website, and a msg was sent to my StackExchange inbox.  I didn't know one could delete a comment, so I assumed a moderator had done so.

Comment: @AlexBecker I have looked at the chat feature but don't know how to use it.

Comment: @ArthurFischer the link remains the same.  If the student wants to ask his question I guess he will have to post it again.